# Image processing in SciLab (convering image to sepia)

Tags: image-processing, scilab

I am doing my homework and I encoured problem.
My task is to write a function in SciLab that converts normal image into sepia.
I have to use algorithm that multiply red color by alpha and blue color by beta where alpha > 1 and beta < 1 and alpha + beta = 2.

This is my code.
For some reason those 2 lines aren't working properly:

```
//img2(i,j,2) = img(i,j);
//img2(i,j,3) = uint8(double(img(i,j))*beta);

function out = Ex2(im,alpha)
[h w d] = size(im);
img2 = uint16(zeros(h,w,d));
img = rgb2gray(im);
beta = 2-alpha;
for i=1:h
    for j=1:w
        img2(i,j,1) = uint16(double(img(i,j))*alpha); //condition if > 255
        if img2(i,j,1) > 255 then
            img2(i,j,1) = 255;
        end
        //img2(i,j,2) = img(i,j);
        //img2(i,j,3) = uint8(double(img(i,j))*beta);
    end
end
out = img2;
endfunction
```

Comment: give us examples of alpha and beta. Also, whats with the `//`? that is not matlab comments. Please post the real matlab function. I am assumign this may be scilab?

Comment: Also, if I change the code to be MATLAB readable, this works fine, I gett very nice sepia images

Comment: Yeah it is SciLab, tagged it also as MatLab because I though those 2 programms are very similar an example of this function's call is Ex2(myimage,1.2);

Comment: I removed the MATLAB tag. However, in MATLAB this just works as it is. if I run `imshow(Ex2(imread('peppers.png'),1.3))` a nice sepia image appears. The only thing I changed are the MATLAB syntax (e.g. enfucntion) and I added `out = uint8(img2);` in the end

Comment: For some reason when I am trying to run this function in SciLab it just gives me the blue loading circle so I have to force SciLab to stop this function's call.

Comment: You are mixing `uint16` and `uint8`.  Could it be the problem?

Comment: Rather not since I defined img2 as uint16.

Answer (score 0):

There is simpler way to get the result

```
function sepia2(img)
    img = rgb2gray(img);
    img = uint16(img);
    [h w] = size(img);

    W = 30;

    for i=1:h
        for j=1:w
            if (img(i,j) + (2*W)) > 255 then
                out(i,j,1) = 255;
                else
                out(i,j,1) = (img(i,j) + (2*W));
            end
            if (img(i,j) + (W)) > 255 then
                out(i,j,2) = 255;
                else
                out(i,j,2) = (img(i,j) + (W));
            end
            out(i,j,3) = img(i,j);
        end
    end

    out = uint8(out);
    imshow(out);
endfunction

img = imread('lena3.jpg');
sepia1(img);
```